# How to call indian language from string file?

Tags: android, string, localization

I am triying to add Indian languages. It is working fine when I used setText.

```
 name=(EditText)loginView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_driver_lname);
 name.setText("fMþ @ûCU");
```

if I add these same text string file and try to call then it is not getting proper value.

```
<string name="frg_lgn_btn_go_online">fMþ @ûCU</string>
```

may I know what is the reason for this. I am more preferring  calling string file rather than adding setText. How to solve this issue.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_driver_lname"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/login_edittext_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_driver_fname"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/min_margin_elements"
            android:text="@string/frg_lgn_btn_go_online"
            android:inputType="text" />
```

i need to use xml set text rather than setText in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the characters when using  in xml.

Try this `fM&#254; @&#251;CU` and see what is the output. You can easily get the escaped strings by pasting it here

http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-escape.html .Hope this helps.

Comment: its working fine only problem with the word start with @.how to slove this issue...for example @&#251;&#180;&#234;f&#251;^&#254;&#232; U&#226;&#251;Ke....

Comment: Hmm that is strange. @ is not an escape character in xml ...can u try placing an empty space in-front of @..?